# authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers/listCallbackUrl/action'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I am working on documenting integration with Azure for later use by colleagues. This is for obtaining an AAD bearer token (done) and using it to get a Logic Apps callback URL. There is the problem, which is to correctly permit the client application. I am not finding documentation on the correct scope to set in the Portal. Also, I don't have the admin permissions myself to try and, so trial-and-error is not an option.

Right now, I have registered in Azure an app with only default permissions. So, when I try the desired action, I get back the error response:

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
>           "message": "The client '{Client Id}' with object id '{object id}' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers/listCallbackUrl/action' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup Name}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflow name}/triggers/manual'."
>       }
>   }

In trying to get the app the right permissions, I am encountering the error in Azure portal:

> You are adding permission(s) that require an admin to consent, users will not be able to use the application until an admin grants permissions to the application.

Which I expect, so I am seeking to tell my admins the exact permission(s) that need to be granted or delegated.

Possibly this can be done in PowerShell and easier than in Portal, or even CLI. I am not wedded to a particular method, just looking for direction or documentation on how to correctly configure the client app. I figure I need to give our app at least Contributor access to the resource group via the Access Control (IAM) tab. However, in this subscription, I do not have the "Add" option there, suggesting I do not have permission to do it.

Right now, I am using the documentation at [register your client application with azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#register-your-client-application-with-azure-ad) but am not finding the steps toward correctly permitting the registered client when I am unable to try it out before explaining it to someone else. Maybe there is more detailed documentation, or a blog post someone knows of that I have not found?

Thank you

Comment: Trying to understand - are you looking to grant permission to an application which will grab the callback url at runtime? Is the client an app or is it a user who would be running a PS script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the callback url at runtime requires permission to invoke the API action [Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/assemblies/listContentCallbackUrl/action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftlogic). You can do this a couple of ways:

- [create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with the required API access. This is nice from a least-privilege perspective, but you're limited to 200 custom roles and you'd need to document what the role is for and track that going forward
- You could leverage the built in role of [logic app contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#logic-app-contributor) which has carte blanche on logic app apis.

Which ever you choose, the next step is to assign the service principal associated to your application (or the user or group account defined in AD) to the role. [Here is a great walkthrough for the role assignment process using the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role) or [using the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#manage-service-principal-roles), if you prefer